# Unexpected result using CTE to perform a random join on two tables for all rows one-to-many

Tags: sql-server, join, random, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I am attempting to randomly join the rows of two tables (TableA and TableB) such that each row in TableA is joined to only one row in TableB and every row in TableB is joined to at least one row in TableA.

For example, a random join of TableA with 5 distinct rows and TableB with 3 distinct rows should result in something like this:

```
TableA  TableB
1       3
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       1
```

However, sometimes not all the rows from TableB are included in the final result; so in the example above might have row 2 from TableB missing because in its place is either row 1 or 3 joined to row 4 on TableA.  You can see this occur by executing the script a number of times and checking the result.  It seems that it is necessary for some reason to use an interim table (@Q) to be able to ensure that a correct result is returned which has all rows from both TableA and TableB.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Also, can someone please advise on what would be a better way to get the desired result?

I understand that sometimes no result is returned due to a failure of some kind in the cross apply and ordering which i have yet to identify and goes to the point that I am sure there is a better way to perform this operation.  I hope that makes sense.  Thanks in advance!

```
    declare @TableA table (
        ID int
        );
    declare @TableB table (
        ID int
        );
    declare @Q table (
        RN int,
        TableAID int,
        TableBID int
        );

    with cte as (
        select
            1 as ID
        union all
        select
            ID + 1
        from cte
        where ID < 5
        )
    insert @TableA (ID)
    select ID from cte;

    with cte as (
        select
            1 as ID
        union all
        select
            ID + 1
        from cte
        where ID < 3
        )
    insert @TableB (ID)
    select ID from cte;

    select * from @TableA;
    select * from @TableB;

    with cte as (
        select
            row_number() over (partition by TableAID order by newid()) as RN,
            TableAID,
            TableBID
        from (
            select
                a.ID as TableAID,
                b.ID as TableBID
            from @TableA as a
            cross apply @TableB as b
            ) as M
        )
    select --All rows from TableB not always included
        TableAID,
        TableBID
    from cte
    where RN in (
        select
            top 1
                iCTE.RN
        from cte as iCTE
        group by iCTE.RN
        having count(distinct iCTE.TableBID) = (
            select count(1) from @TableB
            )
        )
    order by TableAID;

    with cte as (
        select
            row_number() over (partition by TableAID order by newid()) as RN,
            TableAID,
            TableBID
        from (
            select
                a.ID as TableAID,
                b.ID as TableBID
            from @TableA as a
            cross apply @TableB as b
            ) as M
        )
    insert @Q
    select
        RN,
        TableAID,
        TableBID
    from cte;

    select * from @Q;

    select --All rows from both TableA and TableB included
        TableAID,
        TableBID
    from @Q
    where RN in (
        select
            top 1
                iQ.RN
        from @Q as iQ
        group by iQ.RN
        having count(distinct iQ.TableBID) = (
            select count(1) from @TableB
            )
        )
    order by TableAID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gives you what you're looking for...

```
DECLARE 
    @CountA INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableA ta),
    @CountB INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableB tb),
    @MinCount INT;

SELECT @MinCount = CASE WHEN @CountA < @CountB THEN @CountA ELSE @CountB END;

WITH 
    cte_A1 AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
        FROM 
            @TableA ta
        ),
    cte_B1 AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
        FROM 
            @TableB tb
        ),
    cte_A2 AS (
        SELECT 
            a1.ID,
            rn = CASE WHEN a1.rn > @MinCount THEN a1.rn - @MinCount ELSE a1.rn end
        FROM 
            cte_A1 a1
        ),
    cte_B2 AS (
        SELECT 
            b1.ID,
            rn = CASE WHEN b1.rn > @MinCount THEN b1.rn - @MinCount ELSE b1.rn end
        FROM 
            cte_B1 b1
        )
SELECT 
    A = a.ID,
    B = b.ID
FROM 
    cte_A2 a
    JOIN cte_B2 b
        ON a.rn = b.rn;
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution to prevent event where no result is returned due to no full set of TableBID values  being generated; however, it is still necessary on my machine (I am using MSSMS 2008 R2 version 10.50.4000.0) to use an interim table to ensure that a full set from each table is returned; (otherwise, TableAID is missing a random value in 8/10 executions): insert @Q select rn, ID, NULL from cte_A2 union select rn, NULL, ID from cte_B2 select * from @Q select q1.TableAID, q2.TableBID from @Q as q1 join @Q as q2 on q1.RN = q2.RN where q1.TableAID is not NULL and q2.TableBID is not NULL;

Comment: I don't have access to a 2008R2 instance to verify but I don't see anything in the code that isn't compatible with 2008R2.

Comment: Ok; so this answer seems like the best that I am going to get so I will accept it; I did just re-confirm that it is necessary for whatever reason to use an interim table to ensure that a full set from each table is returned as indicated in my previous comment.